# Is it possible to match a regex between specific indexes of a string

Tags: regex

For example if I had a phone number and I wanted to see if either of the last two digits contained a 7. Could I do this purely with regex or do I have to split the string apart first?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex:

```
7\d?$
```

which would match a 7 either at the end or at the second-to-last position. Or, more precisely, it matches a 7 at the end of the string, optionally followed by another digit, which translates to a 7 in one of the last two places.

Comment: The regex went through 4 or 5 iterations (each one functional) since I posted the answer ;-)

Comment: It makes the preceding token optional, that is the regex is equivalent to `7$|7\d$`, but with the question mark I don't have to spell out both options in full.

Answer (score 0):

You could use look-arounds to match at an arbitrary index of a string, we'd use look-behind `(?<=)` to check that we have `start of string`  followed by a fixed number of characters to the left. And look-ahead to `(?=)` to check that we have a fixed number of characters to the right followed by `end of string`.

Index from the start of the string:

```
(?<=^.{N})REGEX
```

Your `REGEX` would match from the N'th (zero based) index, so if you want to check if the 3nd character from the left is `x` in the following string `12x45` then you would use `(?<=^.{2})x` where `x` is the regex to check if the character is `x`.

Using lookahead you could do the same starting from the end:

```
REGEX(?=.{N}$)
```

So to check if either of the last 2 digits are 7 your regex would be `7\d?(?=.{0}$)` (which is the equivalent of what Joey proposed. But as you can see this would work for all indexes (not saying you should use this instead of the simpler one, it's just a more general regex).

If you wanted to check if the 3rd (zero based) character from the left is `x` then not surprisingly you'd have `x(?=.{2}$)`.

You could also combine the two to check between indexes, e.g. you want to check if everything between the 3rd digit at either end is an arbitrary number of `x`'s in `12xxxxxx21` then you you have the following:

```
(?<=^.{2})x*(?=.{2}$)
```

**Note:**
If you just want a match/no match regex then you could do without the look-arounds, but then you would be matching the whole line instead of only what you specify in the `REGEX`.

e.g:

`(?<=^.{2})x*(?=.{2}$)` would match `xxxxxx` for the above example, where as `^.{2}x*.{2}$` would be a match for the strings but it would be matching the whole thing (`12xxxxxx21`) instead of just `xxxxxx`.